# Small Java GUI Program with Inheritance not Working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, inheritance, jframe

I am slightly new to Java (this is my first time creating a program outside of school), and I am having trouble getting my GUI to open correctly. The weird thing is that sometimes (maybe 1 in 10) it opens correctly and works exactly as intended. However, the JFrame usually opens without anything visible inside it. There are pictures at the bottom. Here are my classes:

`GUI.java`:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class GUI {
    
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    
    public GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Word Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
    }
}
```

`MainMenu.java`:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MainMenu extends GUI implements ActionListener {

    private JButton buttonPlay;
    private JButton buttonStats;
    
    public MainMenu() {
        super();
        
        buttonPlay = new JButton("Play");
        panel.add(buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.addActionListener(this);
        buttonStats = new JButton("View Leaderboards");
        panel.add(buttonStats);
        buttonStats.addActionListener(this);
        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new SelectLevel(e.getSource() == buttonPlay);
        frame.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainMenu();
    }
}
```

`SelectLevel.java`:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class SelectLevel extends GUI implements ActionListener {

    
    public SelectLevel(boolean play) {
        super();
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("Level " + i);
            panel.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(this); 
        }
        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Game(e.getActionCommand().charAt(6));
        frame.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainMenu();
    }
}
```

MainMenu and SelectLevel working correctly:

[image: Main Menu Screen (working correctly)]
[image: Select Level Screen (working correctly)]

What I usually get (not working correctly):

[image: What I usually get (not working correctly)]

Comment: Have you tried calling `pack();` after adding new components in your various classes?

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Creating multiple `JFrames` is not a good user experience and not a good coding experience for you.  Generally, you create one and only one `JFrame` and as many `JPanels` as you need to complete the application.  A `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` should be used to switch from one `JPanel` to another.